# Question on simplification of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{(2n+1)(2n+3)}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I am having trouble seeing how $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{(2n+1)(2n+3)}$ equals $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+3}$. I can see $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+3}$ but not $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+3}$. All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This is really about partial fractions decomposition. The hint of O.L is of course right, but if you do not see that, PFD is the way.

Comment: Search **Partial fraction decomposition** It is mostly used for simplifying integrals!

Comment: @ZaidAjaj @ imranfat Thanks! I see how to do it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $2 = (2n+3) - (2n+1)$ then
\begin{align}
\frac{2}{(2n+1)(2n+3)} &= \frac{(2n+3) - (2n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n+3)} = \frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{2n+3}.
\end{align} 
The series then becomes
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(2n+1)(2n+3)} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{2n+3} \right) \\
&= \left( \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{5} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} \right) + \cdots \\
&= \frac{1}{3}. 
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: 
$$\qquad(2n+3)-(2n+1)=2.\qquad$$